# Django: creating dynamic forms

Tags: python, django, forms, models

I have these models and I want to build forms based on the data:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location_id=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    organization=models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Beverage(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location=models.ForeignKey(Location)
    fill_to_standard=models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    order_when_below=models.IntegerField(max_length=10)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Inventory(models.Model):
    location=models.ForeignKey(Location)
    beverage=models.ForeignKey(Beverage)
    units_reported=models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Here is what I want to happen, when a user goes to update inventory for a particular location, I want them to get a form that lists out all the possible beverages for that location (the beverages differ per location) and then create an `Inventory` form for it that will create a new line in the `Inventory` table for each `Beverage` for that `Location`. Each one needs a timestamp so we can have a history. I think I get that I need formsets, but I have not had any success figuring out how to implement them for this. So, this is kind of a two-parter:

1. Is my model design right for this problem?
2. How can I make forms that depend on the number of beverages to build themselves?

Comment: here a clue, I let the credit to the one who will compose a true answer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1: model design - I would drop the location field from the Inventory model, since it is already in the Beverage model, and is redundant.  Otherwise, they look good to me.

Question 2: formsets...

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from my_project.my_app.models import Beverage

class InventoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    units_reported = forms.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = Beverage
        fields = ('name', 'id')
```

views.py

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
from my_project.my_app.models import Beverage, Inventory

def update_inventory(request, location_id):

    InventoryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Beverage, form=InventoryForm)
    qs = Beverage.objects.filter(location=location_id)
    formset = InventoryFormSet(queryset=qs)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = InventoryFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                beverage = form.save(commit=False)
                units_reported = form.cleaned_data['units_reported']
                Inventory(beverage=beverage, units_reported=units_reported).save()
    ...
```

modelformset_factory will create a form for every object (Beverage) in the queryset which is filtered by the desired location, and has an extra field in the customized ModelForm to report units.

Comment: Awesome. Wish I'd see this before I went to bed so I could have slept better :) One last weird thing though, when I write: 

     qs = Beverage.objects.filter(location=location_id)

the query returns nothing

but if I explicitly go get the location first it works:
    
    location = Location.objects.get(location_id=location_id)
    qs=Beverage.objects.filter(location=location)

why would that be??

Comment: Glad to help.  I have a strong suspicion about your queryset issue.  in update_inventory(request, location_id), location_id is a commonly used convention for passing around the pk for instances of a model (also equal to location.id).  Since you named a field called location_id in the Location model, you either need to be extra careful which of these you use at any given moment, or a better solution would be to rename the argument or the field name.  I recommend changing the field name because of the above stated convention.

Comment: ends up "location_id" has nothing to do with it, there are lots of things going here, but they aren't really about the original posting